# Phase transformation at constant volume $V$

Tags: thermodynamics, water, volume

A source heats water inside a vessel (V=constant). As soon as boiling begins, pressure raise up. How will the system evolve? Depends on the heat? 
How would be the relationship between the temperature (Cv) and pressure increasement as the steam (all steam under Tc) is being heated? May condensation occur?

I wrote water as the substance to be examined, but the concepts may apply to several fluids. I hope I have made this sufficiently clear. English is not my native language.

Comment: Are you saying that the vessel is closed (not open to the atmosphere)?

Comment: I assume that liquid water does not fill the entire container, correct?  You are looking for the equilibrium states of this system as temperature increases?  Are you allowed to use the steam tables?

Comment: The vessel is closed. The liquid inside does not fill entire the container. This is not an exercise, if you want to analise the case with a table its ok but I´m looking for the theorical understand of the evolution.

Comment: Remember the 3rd and 4th questions can be think as I start with steam and heat it.